# How can I rotate this polygon into the same position I have rotated my cube?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to rotate the square into the position of the drawn on red square.

I have already used the following for the larger cuboid and it is in the position I want it to be ;

```
glrotatef ( n , 1.0, 0 , 0 ); (n is a changing value on keystrokes)

glrotatef ( x , 0, 1.0, 0 ); (x is a changing value on keystrokes)
```

However when I attempted to do a similar thing with the square it just disappears, I have used glvertex3f and given all of the z values as 0, however upon rotating the z axis I can never reach the point I need, so it must be a combination of x and y as done with the cuboid.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using, or the relevant part of it at least?

Comment: Added relevant code.

Comment: Where are `rect_x`, `rect_y`, `width`, `height` declared? (the ones you use in `draw_rect(...)` call)

Comment: `float rect_x = 100.0f;  float rect_y = 400.0f; , int width = 75; , int height = 115`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `draw_cuboid()` function draws the cube in the origin (which is correct), which is then rotated by the projection matrix modified by your calls to `glRotatef()`. This is the right way to do it. On the other hand, your `draw_rect()` function **does not** draw your rectangle centered at the origin, instead you use the variables `x`and `y`to locate it, which affects the rotation center point.

What you should do is draw the rectangle centered at (0,0),  rotated it, and then translated it to `x`and `y`.

The image below (right) exemplifies what is going on when you draw your rectangle. Image taken from [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html).

Also, note that you are using a **deprecated OpenGL code**. You should draw your polygons using modern OpenGL. [**Here**](https://open.gl/drawing) there is a very nice tutorial on how to do it.

[image: Rotation]

Comment: That figure alongside your explanation is very helpful! I have managed to get the exact same output by making the rect central (at the origin), however once I begin to rotate at any degree (very small increments/decrements) it provides very wierd shapes other than my rect rotated. Should it not provide the same position the cuboid is tilted at, as they were both at the origin?                           [Picture](http://postimg.org/image/civv6ymhp/)

Comment: Another problem I've just encountered is that the value for the x + y positions are no longer valid, hence when I move the rect about it provides incorrect co-ordinates, everything else becomes messed up as some collision detecting relies on those values. If its not possible to update the values to the correct position I may have to leave this out, but it would be a very useful addition. As it stands I am unable to tilt it correctly anyway, I may be missing something.

Comment: @CodeStack How are you drawing the rectangle? Is the center of it at the (0,0), or is one of its corners in the (0,0). For example, for a rectangle of size `x` times `y`, vertices should be `(-x/2,y/2), (x/2,y/2), (x/2,-y/2) and (-x/2,-y/2)`

Comment: @CodeStack Also, your `draw_rect` function should only take `width` and `height` as a parameters. The actual location, `x`and `y`, should be set by `glTranslatef`. But bare in mind that this is a deprecated method that should not be used...

Comment: I am limited to using some of these methods as the compiler I must use is aged, as part of a project it has to work on the machines it will be submitted onto.  I had updated the draw_rect function and it does only take x & y parameters now, that only partially solved the problem, the rect starts disappearing once rotated after the translation, if I attempt to rotate then translate nothing happens ( it is centered ), as once I take the rotation call out it immediately translates into the correct position. I will post the updated code in a few mins

Comment: I have changed the display function a bit to what it looks like now, the major problem is the lack of rotation before translating, as its possible to do it the other way around?

Comment: Another problem is that you are mixing GL_PROJECTION and GL_MODELVIEW. Your transformations should be applied to MODELVIEW.